# Today Extension (Widget) not getting updated during app update

Tags: ios, widget, ios8-today-widget

I have an app in appstore containing a widget and it works fine. Now when i tried to give an update  for the existing widget and tried over installing through Xcode, the app gets updated , but the widget is not getting replaced with the new version. Please provide a solution.

Comment: try restarting the device..

Comment: This seems to be an issue only while installing the new version through Xcode.. Today my app got released to apptore and the widget gets updated perfectly through itunes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

- First install a older version
- Open it container app, and drop down the today view
- Then install the new one
- Drop down today view again
- It just keeping the old style

After that, I debug the today widget through Xcode

- First time, Xcode report a error with some message lick "Lost connection"
- Stop debug
- Run debug again
- The today view drop down automatically and then become the new version style

I wish it would be all right when submit to AppStore just like you said. :(

Comment: It will work fine in the Appstore . Its just Xcode issue, try installing the  new version of your app using itunes in your mac , even there it works fine.